# Rasterio how to find same values in excel

Tags: geotiff-tiff, rasterio, matplotlib, differences

I have two geographical tiff files, the difference is 20 years. There are some values ​​in the pixels of these drawings. I need to find differences between the second file and the first one. I tried to do it through Rasterio. Hint, you can subtract the second dataframe from the first and a value of 0 will mean that the dataframe is the same in this place.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import rasterio as ras
import rioxarray as rxr
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw

bor = ras.open(r'C:\Users\User\tif50.tif')
bur = ras.open(r'C:\Users\User\tif150.tif')

borov = bor.read(1)
burov = bur.read(1)


plt.imshow(borov, cmap='pink')

plt.imshow(burov, cmap='pink')

dataarray1 = rxr.open_rasterio(r'C:\Users\User\tif50.tif')
dataarray2 = rxr.open_rasterio(r'C:\Users\User\tif150.tif')
bur_1 = dataarray1[0].to_pandas()
bur_2 = dataarray2[0].to_pandas()

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    display(bur_1)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    display(bur_2)

bur1_2 = pd.concat([bur_1, bur_2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    display(bur1_2)

plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.imshow(bur1_2, cmap='pink')

bor2_1 = bur_2.subtract(bur_1, axis = None)


with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    display(bor2_1)


plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.imshow(bor2_1, cmap='pink')

sr = (bur_1 + bur_2) / 2
plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.imshow(sr[-2<sr<2],cmap = 'terrain_r')


with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None):
    display(sr)

display(bur_2.compare(bor2_1))


plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.imshow(bur_1.compare(bur_2), cmap='pink')


bor2_1 < 0 *(-1)
plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
plt.imshow(bor2_1 < 0.002, cmap='pink_r')
```

Comment: leaving the teacher's **hint** in is a bit of a give away you are trying to get us to do your homework

Comment: @IanTurton No, my teacher told me to do this task differently, I need to change the solution in the hint, but I can’t do it, so I ask for help

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works